# Atmega8:Led as binary counter

Tags: avr, atmega

I am trying to write a program for LED as a binary counter in atmega8 controller.

The first 2 bits(MSB) is connected to portd and last 6 bits are connected to port c:

Here is my code:

```
#define F_CPU 10000000UL//clock frequency
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>//header for the delay


int main(void)
{
    /* main function */
    DDRC=0b11111111;//to make all the port in C as output
    DDRD =0b11111111;//to make all the port in D as output
    int x=0,a=64,b=128,c=192;//input variables
    while (1) 
    {
        //for nos from 0 to 64
        if(x<64)
        {
        PORTC = x;
        PORTD = 0b00000000;
        _delay_ms(200);
        x++;
        }//if no is equal to 64 then the if condition breaks

        //for nos from 64 to 128
        x=0;//initializing to 0

        if((a<128) && (x<64))
        {
                PORTC = x;
                PORTD = 0b01000000;
                _delay_ms(200);
                x++;
                a++;
        }//if no is equal to 128 then the if condition breaks

        //for nos from 128 to 192
        x=0;//initializing to 0

        if((b<192) && (x<64))
        {
                PORTC = x;
                PORTD = 0b10000000;
                _delay_ms(200);
                x++;
                b++;
        }//if no is equal to 192 then the if condition breaks

        //for nos from 192 to 256
        x=0;//initializing to 0

        if((c<256) && (x<64))
        {
                PORTC = x;
                PORTD = 0b11000000;
                _delay_ms(200);
                x++;
                c++;
        }//if no is equal to 256 then the if condition breaks

        //initializing the variables to keep the while loop running
        x=0;
        a=64;
        b=128;
        c=192;
    }
}

  }
}
```

Could you please let me know whether the code is written in a proper way and if it works or not.

Comment: Why don't you test it and see?

Comment: Hi I was searching to install the driver software to connect my device. Hence in the meantime I just worked with the code and idea behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, first please tell us what exactly are you trying to do?

I must admit that the **idea** behind your code is correct (x is the counter. a and b and c are helper variables. That's right). BUT absolutely the code above won't work and isn't the optimum way:

1. In the while loop you are continuously zeroing the X variable.
2. To keep the record of how many (64-count) periods did X pass, you are introducing a and b and c. You could've done it with only 'a'.
3. The code does not benefit from "Don't Repeat Yourself" rule of programming (see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You have done everything 4 times. What if you had to store a 16-bit number with 6 bits on one port and 10 bits on another port!! :D

My idea:
(1) The following code uses bitwise-AND operator to separate first 6 bits and 2 remaining bits

```
int x;
while (1)
{
   x = x + 1;
   if (x >= 256) x = 0;
   PORTC = x & (0x3F); //or: x & (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32)
   PORTD = x & (0xC0); //or: x & (64 + 128)
   delay_ms(200);
}
```

My friend, if you are going to learn Microcontroller programming, BE SURE TO LEARN what **&**, **|**, **^**, **~**, **<<**, **>>**, etc. will do. Otherwise you will be stuck in every part of coding on microcontrollers.

Idea(2): If you are not easy with these bitwise operators, you could use modulo (%) and division (/) operator (I don't really suggest this. Some compilers are really stupid on optimizing codes requiring % and /).

```
int x;
while (1)
{
   x = x + 1;
   if (x >= 256) x = 0;
   PORTC = x % (64); //result is 0 to 63.
   PORTD = (x / (64)) * 64; //this will essentially strip lower 6 bits of x.
   delay_ms(200);
}
```

As you gain experience in BITWISE operators, you will find out that there are million more ways to do this!! :D

Comment: thanks all for the reply:) I was trying to implement led as binary counter with 2 different ports. Actually I was trying to find the isp driver to connect with my device so in the mean time I just tried to write the code. So my concern was whether using 2 different ports for the connection will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* using an unsigned char data type means the variable is 8 bit and therefore
   will only count from 0 to 255
   initialising to zero gives it a definate value to start at

*/
unsigned char x = 0; 

while (1)
{
   x++; //C short hand
   PORTC = x & (0x3F); //or: x & (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32)
   PORTD = x & (0xC0); //or: x & (64 + 128)
   delay_ms(200);
}
```

Comment: If you know you need an unsigned 8 bit integer, just use `uint8_t`. That type says exactly what you want.

Comment: Yea I know but I'm making a point, unsigned and char are part of the language whereas uint8_t is actually a typedef included in a header file

Comment: An *implementation defined* part of the language.

Comment: Yes I agree, I tend to use the stdint.h defs all the time tbh. But the point of my answer was not how to define an 8bit number but how to use it.